# Cursor looping throughout a function or a view

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

I have a cursor looping throughout a Table-valued function like in the code below :

```
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT *        
            from    [dbo].[GetStock]()
                    ...
```

My question is : Does the cursor execute the function at each iteration ? same question for a View.
Regards

Comment: The easiest, quickest answer to any question like this is "use SQL Profiler and [execution plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.100).aspx) to see for yourself". If the information from those tools is unclear in any way then feel free to ask about the specific details, but you will learn more by trying to answer your own question first.

Comment: By reading your answer, I realized how lazy I am.Frankly, I haven't tried anything. Thanks! I'll give it an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of cursor:

- if it is a static cursor, then it will only execute the SELECT once, placing the result in a temporary table and get the results one by one from the temporary table
- if it's a dynamic cursor, then it will get the results one by one from the query
- if it's a keyset-driven cursor, then it will get the key for each qualifying row when the cursor is opened, and the rest of the columns one by one, from the original query
- if it's a fast forward cursor, it behaves like a dynamic cursor when result has a unique key or like a static cursor when there is no unique key.

There are several restrictions regarding the query which will affect the type of the cursor, listed here: [Using Implicit Cursor Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190641.aspx).

You can find out the cursor type by using the sp_describe_cursor procedure. See the [sp_describe_cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173806.aspx) topic for a code sample.

For multi-statement UDF-s, you are most likely to get a keyset-driven cursor (if the result table has a unique key) or a static cursor (if the result table does not have a unique key). For inline UDF-s, it depends on the query and the underlying tables.

I guess you have a multi-statement UDF and in this case you should avoid keyset-driven cursors by specifying STATIC when you declare the cursor.